# Unable to set initialtext in ios9 in native facebook share dialog

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios9

I am trying to set initial text to SLComposeViewController in iOS 9 , but it is displaying blank in dialog.

Here is my code.

```
 SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

                 NSString *initialText = @"Tesing text issue.";

                 if (initialText != Nil)
                 {
                     [composeController setInitialText:initialText];
                 }
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                {
                                    //show progress hud here
                                    [self presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];
                            });
```

I have aslo check this in another sharing app, they have also same issue. Can anybody have any workaround here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has deprecated the api to set initial text programmatically while sharing. Below are the references:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial text using graph API and custom share dialogue.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios#custom